# Redux reducer to change the state of another reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there is any way that one reducer can change the state of its own as well as states of different reducers as well.
eg.

`reducer1(state=initialstate,action){}`

`reducer2(state=initialstate,action){}`

and there is reducer3

`reducer3(state=initialstate,action){}`

When action for reducer3 is going to dispatch ,I want that somehow ,reducer3 will able to  change the state of reducer1 or reducer2 or both as well.

Comment: Does the state object you are passing in reducer 3 has the properties which the  reducer 2 and reducer 1 updates . If yes then you can change it . Else you won't be able to do it inside the reducer function . You need to have one reducer which has all the reducer 1,2 and 3 states

Comment: all three are independent

Comment: Can't you handle the same action in each reducer? Please provide more details